# Semi-colon, comma, or two separate sentences?

Tags: punctuation

Which of these is correct:

Thanks. I appreciate it.

Thanks, I appreciate it.

Thanks; I appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  You might also want to check out our sister site, http://ell.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

Well, "Thanks" can't be called an independent clause, thus comma is OK too. Otherwise you'd get a  [comma splice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice).

Thus, all three are OK.